# I need a fast sort for a project that isnt Merge, Quicksort, or heapsort

Tags: sorting, big-o

I've been looking for an hour or so for sorts that aren't listed above. I asked elsewhere but people just responded with the slowest sorts possible. Please help. It has to be no slower than O(n log n).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the fastest algorithm to sort data really depends on the data being sorted.

You could use Counting sort, which takes `O(N + R)`; where `R` is the range of values. Therefore the larger the range of elements the time increases.

Or Fast sort:
The quickest possible way to sort an array of data would be to just scan the data which would give you `N` choices for the first element, `N - 1` choices for the second element and so on until the last element which would have only `1` choice. This ends up in a sorting algorithm that can be done in `O(N!)` . `N!` can be approximated to `2^(N * log N)`; therefore Fast sort is done in `O(N * log N)`.

No possible sorting algorithm exists which can be sort faster than `O(N * log N)`.

A trick to sort faster is with using an infinite number of processors, which can bring the time complexity down to `0(log N)` but for large `N` you can see how this would not be practical.

Or one could use `log N` processors working in parallel to bring the time complexity to `O(N)`. But again, parallel processing is more of a trick than anything. The algorithm itself is not compressed to `O(N)`.